# python beautifulsoup extract number of appearance between tag

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup, extract

I want to extract the number of "file it" between tag in web page.
Here is my code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

nameList = bsObj.findAll(text="file it")
print(len(nameList))
```

In case of "file it" or "Download", it works well with the result 1.
In case of "Hall of Fame", it works well with the result 2.

But in case of "the discussion group", it should be 2 but it doesn't work and the result is 0.

why do i get result 0 in "the discussion group" case or "get the source code" case?

Comment: If you look at the page source, there is a newline between, `"the discussion\ngroup"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
nameList = bsObj.findAll(text=re.compile(r"the\s+discussion\sgroup"))
```

use `\s+` in regex to match all the white space including `\n`